# Git merge with different histories

Tags: git

I have two branches, both with different commit histories. However, currently, the files in both branches are the exact same.

Now, if I make commits from now on to master, how can I merge the second branch with them?

Comment: The question is not entirely clear, can you explain more your situation and what you're trying to do?  Is this question basically asking "How do I merge branches in Git?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have two branches, `master` and `devel`, and their actual file content is currently identical (`git diff master devel` prints empty output). You can merge these branches using this:

```
git checkout master
git merge -s ours devel
```

`-s ours` means using `ours` strategy, that is, `master` content prevails over `devel` content. However, since `devel` file content is exactly the same, it should not make any difference for you. However, `devel` history will be present in `git log`, even if you were to delete `devel` branch altogether.